# Working with elements inside a dynamically loaded <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery

ON the display page, I'm loading contents into a container div using ("#mydiv").load("myphpfile.php"); This works fine. My question is, how do I work with elements inside that loaded div?

Here is the code sample:

```
<div id="contents"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#contents").load("___server_side.php");
  $("#message").click(function(){
    console.log('clicked');
  });
</script>
```

"#message" is an element in the loaded div. How do I access it and assign functions to it from the display page?

Comment: What do you mean by "*active page*"? And when did you set this listener to the `#message` before or after the `.load` ?

Comment: You would use [Event Delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: Here is the code sample: 

<div id="contents"></div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#contents").load("___server_side.php");

$("#message").click(function(){
    console.log('clicked');
});
</script>

#message is an element in the loaded div. How do I access it ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Once the content is loaded, you can apply events like normal. If you want to before they are loaded, you can use `.on()`.

Comment: Thanks guys. Assuming Twisty is correct, I can't get the code I posted above to work. Do you see an error in it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your code as is, yet I would add a `.ready()`.

```
<div id="contents"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#contents").load("___server_side.php");
  $("#message").ready(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
      console.log('clicked');
    });
  });
</script>
```

Another option is to add the event callback once loading is finished.

```
<div id="contents"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#contents").load("___server_side.php", function(){
    $("#message", this).click(function(){
      console.log('clicked');
    });
  });
</script>
```

Otherwise I would use the `.on()` option.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#contents").on("click", "#message", function(){
    console.log('clicked');
  });
  $("#contents").load("___server_side.php");
</script>

<div id="contents"></div>
```

See More:

- https://api.jquery.com/load/
- https://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @baby_yoda Great! Once the element is `ready` then you can assign the callback. Without it, it may not have loaded to the DOM by the time you tried to assign it.

Comment: @baby_yoda if it did help, I hope you want to upvote it or mark it as the answer. You may also want to take the Tour so you can know more about the site: https://stackoverflow.com/tour